# Opencart Mysql query for customers who order more then 1 times

Tags: mysql

I am using `Opencart 2.3.0.2` I am creating a customer sales module.

In this module I want to get customers who order more than once.

This is the query I have used

`SELECT * FROM oc_order o LEFT JOIN oc_customer oc ON (o.customer_id = oc.customer_id) WHERE  (SELECT * FROM oc_order WHERE customer_id=o.customer_id)`

> But it shows `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)` error

Is there any query for get customers who order more then one time?

Comment: You may have a better solution if you can post some sample data here.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: you asking sample data for kchason query?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai this is my result https://ibb.co/jmbG2T

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a condition for your query. You probably want to use `WHERE EXISTS` ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)).

> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and
>   NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE...

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    oc_order o 
LEFT JOIN 
    oc_customer oc 
    ON (o.customer_id = oc.customer_id) 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        oc_order 
    WHERE 
        customer_id=o.customer_id
)
```

Though, if you're looking for a count of orders, you may want to only look for those that have more than 1 order.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    oc_order o 
LEFT JOIN 
    oc_customer oc 
    ON (o.customer_id = oc.customer_id) 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(order_id) 
    FROM 
        oc_order 
    WHERE 
        customer_id=o.customer_id
    GROUP BY
        customer_id
    HAVING
        COUNT(order_id) > 1
)
```

I'm not familiar with the schema, and I'm not sure what the order_id column should acutally be.

Comment: I don't think this is going to solve your purpose as it is not counting `>1`.

Comment: Was literally editing it as you commented, thanks! :D